# Save all not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I make changes to a file there is no dirty file mark (the dot) displayed in the tab bar next to the file name. If I try to Save All, it doesn't save the file. However, if I save the file with Save option, it does save the file to disk. Autosave is not enabled.

Version: 1.85.1 (Universal)
Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Date: 2023-12-13T09:48:06.308Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.2.0

Comment: I doubt it has to do with extensions, but it doesn't hurt to check: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: also, does this happen regardless of what language mode you select? try switch between different language modes (use `Change Language Mode` in command palette) and seeing if that makes any difference. Try also checking if you get the dirty indicator (white dot) in new untitled editor tabs.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "save the file with Save option"? You mean from the menubar's File > Save menu item?

Comment: @starball, it might have to do with extensions, I'm still not 100% sure but it seems to be working fine. I'll use the bisect method to figure out the culprit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @starball, it works fine after disabling Name: angular2-switcher
Id: infinity1207.angular2-switcher
Description: Easily navigate to `typescript`|`template`|`style` in angular2 project.
Version: 0.4.0
Publisher: infinity1207
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=infinity1207.angular2-switcher

Comment: @starball, also your answer is correct so if you post it, I can accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour was found by [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to be cause by the [`infinity1207.angular2-switcher`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=infinity1207.angular2-switcher) extension. For now, if you're not using it, you can just disable the extension, or disable it at least in the workspaces where you're not using it. I'd suggest raising an issue ticket to [its issue tracker](https://github.com/infinity1207/angular2-switcher/issues/new) to let its maintainers know about this.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.